# reStructuredText for SQL?

Tags: sql, restructuredtext, docutils

I am trying to use DocUtils and reStructuredText to comment SQL code.  I can get this to work when I include the markup inside multi-line comments.  I then use --Some text:: to introduce each block of code.

I cannot get internal hyperlinks to work.  I would like to write
-- .. Step1_:
but the parser ignores this because of the leading comment.  Using a multi-line style also fails. Is there a way to get this to work?

Here's an example:

```
/*
==========
this query
==========
:Author: Me

Outline
==========

- Create table 1

- Create table 2

- Output the result

*/

-- _Step1: build the table::

    create table table1

-- _Step2: use Step1_ to build table 2::

    create table table2
```

Answer (score 6):

I use Sphinx for restructure text. The syntax for internal hyperlinks would be, for example,

```
.. step1:

.. code-block:: sql

   create table table1     

This is later text in which an internal hyperlink occurs. Note
the indention of create table table1. It is part
of the .. code-block:: sql directive, so it must be indented.
Now here comes the internal link. Please see :ref:`step1` as
to how to create the table.
```

Answer (score 0):

`code-block` supported by `docutils` version `0.10` or may be `0.9`.